# How to disable the check in with out giving the task or bug id

Tags: tfs, devops, workitem

i am using the TFS 2013 version and i want to deny the check ins without giving the work item ids.  please suggest me how to make the work item type mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use check in policy to handle your scenario.

> These check-in policies require the user to take actions when they
>   conduct a check-in to source control, for example a user can be
>   required to associate a work item with a changeset.

**To create a check-in policy:**

1. From Team Explorer, select the **Settings** page, then select Source
   Control under the Project section.The Source Control Settings dialog box appears.
2. Click the **Check-in Policy** tab and then click **Add**. The Add Check-in
   Policy dialog box appears.
3. In the Check-in Policy list, select the policy type you want and
   then click OK.

   In your case, just select **Work Items**, the policy is added to the list that a work item must be associated with the check in.

When you are satisfied with the settings for the check-in policies, click OK; the new check-in policy now displays with future check-ins. Others have to select related work item ID in pending changes page, otherwise he will not be able to check in code.

More  details please take a look at this blog: [Add Check-In Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-check-policies?view=azure-devops)